# How to change colors on Plotly treemap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I need assistance with changing the colors on my treemap. I'm not sure where to tweak the code to achieve this. Please find my code belowe. Any idea how to do this? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

dtd7 <- structure(
list(
topic = structure(
  c(9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L),
  .Label = c("Owners' Equivalent Rent of Residences", "Rent of 
Primary Residence",
             "New Vehicles", "Used Cars and Trucks", "Cereals And 
bakery Products",
             "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair", "Airline 
Fares",
             "Apparel", "Alcoholic Beverages", "Hospital 
Services",
             "Tobacco and Smoking", "Physicians Services", 
"Gasoline All Types",
             "Electricity", "Utility (Piped) Gas Services",
             "Nonalcoholic Beverages and Beverage Materials",
             "Food Away From Home", "Meats Poultry Fish and", 
             "Fruits and Vegetables", "Dairy and Related 
Products",
             "Cereals And bakery Products", "Other Foods at 
Home"),
  class = "factor"),
 n = structure(
  c(4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 1L),
  .Label = c("6.7", "6.9", "1.4", "3.8", "19.2", "8.5", "12.1", 
"1.1", "5", "2.9", 
             "6.3", "7.7", "0.7", "8.9", "3.4", "10.4", "2.9", 
"5.3", "0.1", "0.4", 
             "1.4", "3.4", "3.3"),
  class = "factor")
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -13L)
)



plot_ly(
dtd7 %>% 
  mutate(n = as.numeric(as.character(n))), #transform to 
numeric
labels = ~topic,
parents = NA,
values = ~n,
type = 'treemap',
hovertemplate = "Category: %{label}<br>Percent: %{value}%<extra>. 
</extra>" #added % 
after value!
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `marker.colorscale` attribute to assign colors. You can either use a list of colors, or you can provide a color scale like below:

```
plot_ly(
  dtd7 %>% 
    mutate(n = as.numeric(as.character(n))), 
  labels = ~topic,
  parents = NA,
  values = ~n,
  type = 'treemap',
  hovertemplate = "Category: %{label}<br>Percent: %{value}%<extra>. 
</extra>",
  marker=list(colorscale='Reds'))
)
```

You can use a list of colors instead like this:

```
 marker=list(colors=c("#000", "royalblue", "lightgray", "purple", "#FFF", "lightgray", "lightblue"))
```

You can also use the `treecolorway` attribute to assign colors.

For furthe reading, refer to the the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/r/treemaps/).